# Added incorrect Git remote; can't remove it or overwrite it with another remote

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I incorrectly added the wrong remote origin for my git repo. I never explicitly set my repo's remote origin. I think it must have been set by default when, before setting up a remote origin, I ran:

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git
```

I did this so that in case the code from the original (upstream) repo from which I forked changed, the changes would also be uploaded and reflected in my fork. I can't be sure that this command set my remote origin since I am still in the early stages of getting acquainted with git, but when ran

```
$ git remote -v
```

git told me that that my origin was: https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git. I've tried removing this remote and overwriting it, but neither work. When trying to remove it, I get the error message - fatal: No such remote, and when I try to overwrite it, I get the error messgae - fatal: remote origin already exists. These two error messages seem to be contradictory, so I am not sure how to proceed. Can anyone help me understand what is going on better and how I can get git to reset my remote to the proper url?

Here are the git commands I ran and the output that git gave for them:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git (push)

$ git remote rm https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git
fatal: No such remote: https://github.com/hackreactor/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git

$ git remote add origin  https://github.com/BLuEScioN/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git remote rm` takes the name of the remote (in this case `origin`) as its command.

Alternatively you can also just update the URL of the remote like so:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/BLuEScioN/HRATX24-javascript-koans.git
```